# Search substring according to pattern in cells

Tags: excel, excel-2013

Consider the following strings (each one in its own cell):

```
ROUND1|ID001|Some more info|TASK001|More info
RND2|TASK053|ID001|Some info|
TASK533|TD032|Some info|ROUND52|News
```

For each I have to take the substring `TASKxxx`:

```
TASK001
TASK053
TASK533
```

The pattern is always the same:

- `TASK` can be anywhere in the string
- It is always `TASK` + 3 digits (`TASK001`, `TASK432`, ...)

How can I do this in Excel?

Answer (score 0):

If these values are in column A, you can get `TASK001` out of the first value using this formula in column B:

`=MID(A1,SEARCH("TASK",A1),7)`